# Creating string from byte[] not working the same on Ubuntu as on Windows java

Tags: java, character-encoding

```
public class chartests {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte char255 = -5;
        byte[] single = new byte[1];
        single[0] = char255;
        String output = new String(single);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

This code demonstrates a problem I am having with a little server application I am making.

So, when I run this on my windows machine, a 'u' character with an accent over it is printed out. When I run this on my Ubuntu a machine a '?' unknown character is printed out.

Obviously this is because the Ubuntu machine is not supporting characters outside the 127 ascii range.

How can I explicitly encode and decode my strings using a certain encoding? I want an encoding which is exactly one byte per character as well, as I'm more concerned with what bytes are coming across than what characters, and don't want to deal with the headache of having more than one byte per character in my parser. I'm not certain UTF-8 would be acceptable either.

The behavior I have on my windows machine is what I want to happen on Ubuntu. How can I get my Ubuntu machine to decode the -5 byte as an accented u?

Comment: `Ubuntu machine is not supporting characters outside the 127 ascii range`  What?!  Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: _How can I explicitly encode and decode my strings using a certain encoding?_ Look at the overloaded `getBytes` methods and `String` constructors.

Comment: You have to make your output device supports the encoding of the content you send it. Otherwise, it might parse it in an unexpected manner.

Comment: *How can I get my Ubuntu machine to decode the -5 byte as an accented u?* You use an encoding where byte `0xFB` is a `û`, e.g. `ISO-8859-1`, however if you are only concerned with the bytes, why convert to text? Byte `0x07` won't display on either platform, but may be noisy.

Comment: Windows uses a default character set derived from the regional settings (for example `Cp1252` in Western Europe), while on Linux it is usually `utf-8`. You should **always** be explicit with your character sets, unless you have made sure relying on the system default is ok (and it usually isn't).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `java.lang.String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)` could make sure your code work as expected. For example:

```
new String(new byte[]{-5},"ISO8859-1")
```

If you ignore the charsetName parameter, the default charset will be System property `file.encoding`. The value maybe different on different environment. This rule also apply to `java.io.InputStreamReader` and other API which supply charsetName parameter.